# How do i populate a php dropdown with data relating to a previous dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, sql

my original dropdown works fine:

```
{function query(){
  $classes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class") or die("Could not search!");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($classes)) {    
    echo '<option value="' . $row['class_name'] . '">' . $row['class_name'] . '</option>';
  }
}}
```

The selected value from the dropdown is assigned to the $class variable.

However my second dropdown which is designed to pull all data relating to the $class variable originating from the first dropdown is empty:

```
{function findpupil(){
  $pupils = mysql_query("SELECT * from pupil WHERE class_name='$class'") or die("Could not search!");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pupils)) {    
      echo '<option value="' . $row['pupil_id'] . '">' . $row['pupil_id'] . '</option>';
    }
  }
}
```

Both queries are called in HTML like so:

```
<select class="input username" name="class">
    <?php query() ?>
</select>
<select class="input username" name="pupil">
    <?php findpupil() ?>
</select>
```

Why is the second dropdown empty? All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you don't pass any variables into your second function, findpupil().
you need to pass the $class variable you use in that query.

Comment: Not sure to understand how you want to acheive this.  But, if you want to populate a second dropdown based on the first one, you have two options:

- Reload the page by passing the selected option of the first dropdown
- Use AJAX to load the second dropdown.

In both, you need to define a javascript action on the select box

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. How exactly would i pass the selected option and stay on the same page? set the form (action="") empty?

Could you please provide an example as how to do this? Really struggling.

Comment: you probably should look into ajax, you can dynamically create a dropdown by using ajax to run a php script and pass that data into a section of your page